# What is the input validation pattern for S3 filenames?

Tags: javascript, regex, amazon-s3

I'm struggling to create the [pattern expression](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#the-pattern-attribute) for [S3 filenames](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html#object-key-guidelines). Has anyone figured it out?

```html
<form>
<input type=text pattern="[0-9][A-Z][a-z]+" id=filename autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" value="01YES">
<input type=submit value="Upload">
</form>
```

Comment: What is the problem with your approach?

Comment: The value 01YES should work, but it doesn't

Comment: You allowed only one digit in your regex and expect `01YES` with two digits match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing the regex pattern expression with the following:

```
([0-9]|[A-Z]|[a-z]|[!\-_.*'\(\)])+
```

Where `+` means **1 or more** of the preceding token. This is changable into an `*` which means **0 or more** of the preceding token if you will require it.

Comment: @hendry Try it with the new regex, I've edited my answer.

Comment: You've also omitted the "safe" special characters listed upon https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html#object-key-guidelines btw

Comment: @hendry You can try for now `([0-9]|[A-Z]|[a-z]|[!\-_.*'\(\)])+` but if you have forbidden character (let's say '#'), it will most probably break the directory name in two. Let me know how it works.